# Load Custom Ribbon Drop Down List Excel

Tags: excel, xml, vba, ribbon

I am trying to figure how to trigger getSelectedItemID and getItemLabel for a drop down in custom UI ribbon in Excel. I am trying to build the list for the drop down and display the previous value from the previous session. I have tried to include myribbon.invalidate in the onload script.

XML code

```
             <dropDown id="dropDown" label="GoTo"
                onAction="Bookmark_dropdown_onAction" 
                getSelectedItemID="Bookmark_dropdown_getSelectedItemID" 
                getItemLabel="Bookmark_dropdown_getItemLabel" 
                getItemID="Bookmark_dropdown_getItemID" 
                getItemCount="Bookmark_dropdown_getItemCount">
```

VBA code

```
Public Sub Bookmark_dropdown_getItemCount(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
returnedVal = LastRow_BookMark - 1
End Sub

Public Sub Bookmark_dropdown_getItemID(control As IRibbonControl, index As Integer, ByRef id)
id = "ID Sheet: " & index

End Sub

Public Sub Bookmark_dropdown_getItemLabel(control As IRibbonControl, index As Integer, _
ByRef returnedVal)
returnedVal = BookMark_WS.Cells(index + 2, 1)
End Sub

Public Sub Bookmark_dropdown_getSelectedItemID(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef id)
id = WS.Range("SelectedBookMark")
End Sub
```

Comment: Had a typo in one of my macros. Got it sorted out.

Comment: If you want, you can post the typo fix as the answer for other users that might see this question in the future.